# What would happen if you wore 'soft suit'(IVA suit) in the vacuum of space?

Tags: spacesuits, eva

I am looking for the effects (mainly in the short term) that you would experience if you were to go on an EVA wearing an IVA suit. For example, I don't think that the IVA suits have any form of protection from radiation. Unlike most EVA suits that have reflective coating made from Mylar.

I am mainly looking for things you would experience on that EVA, not a couple of days-years after(if you survived), but anything is useful :)

Comment: This would depend on the particular IVA suit and its design specifics, do you have any individual IVA suit in mind? E.g. differences between Orlan (EVA) and Sokol (IVA) suits? IVA suits are usually not made for mobility and autonomy required during EVA and lack own life support system (i.e. umbilical only), but some might also only be comfortable enough in equivalent ambient to internal pressure and would balloon in the vacuum of space, and/or their thermal design to remove excess heat during movement or direct exposure to the Sun wouldn't be sufficient, and so on. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Oh ok, well lets say for instance an Advanced Crew Escape Suit.

Answer (score 4):

An astronaut entering an EVA in an ACES would probably suffocate before they are boiled to death (lucky them).

The life support system is normally plugged into the spacecraft. There is only a 10 minute backup oxygen supply in the suit itself. Meanwhile the unfavorable  [ratio of absorptivity to emittance](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5246/why-is-gold-used-in-space-technology-to-protection-from-heat-radiation/5248#5248) of the pumpkin orange suit would cause it to heat up quickly. This is not helped by the fact that the astronauts body heat has nowhere to go. And it is conceivable they might be "agitated" and therefore give off a fair bit of body heat in this situation.

I assume heat capacity the stagnant water in the water cooling system of the suit together with its many cloth layers would keep the suit at survivable temperatures for that time, though. Long enough for the oxygen to run out at least.

Comment: Backup oxygen supply alone is not sufficient, there must be also a backup scrubber for CO2.