# What is that cone-shaped thingy on most orbiters?

Tags: identify-this-object, uncrewed-spaceflight, mars-orbiters

Whether you're Looking at MRO, Odyssey, Juno, or MAVEN, you might notice it. That odd cone on the top or bottom of the spacecraft. Does anyone know what it is?[image: MRO]

Comment: See https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26889/why-is-sentinel-3bs-dish-antenna-overwrapped-with-metallized-film

Answer (score 3):

It is the parabolic reflector of the antenna used for uplink and downlink to the ground station on Earth. A high gain narrow beam antenna is needed.

For transfer from the spacecraft to Earth the reflector generates a narrow beam to increase the signal amplitude at the ground station.

For transfer from Earth to spacecraft the reflector enlarges the receiving area to increase the signal amplitude to the receiver of the spacecraft.

Your image shows the back side of the parabolic reflector. There is a foil cover to protect against micrometeorites and to limit heating of the dish by the sunlight.

Comment: cool, but why not use a more conventional looking antenna?

Comment: @DekoRevinio Never seen a TV satellite dish antenna mounted to a house? Using a more conventional looking antenna which does not work over the huge distances does not make sense.

Comment: @uwe. Other images show what appears to be a mylar material "enclosing" the parabolic dish and feed. (That's my guess.) See https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mars_Odyssey_over_Valles_Marineris_illustration.jpg. I think this is why the OP is asking about the "cone shaped item" since it does not appear to be an obvious antenna of any type that is typically seen. Do you know the purpose of the cone covering?

Comment: @Uwe good point. after further research I found that they chose that version of the antenna because it's just flat out better than most other options. And yes, I have seen satellite dishes on houses before, but none of them have that tinfoil-ish material covering them

Comment: @JohnHoltz "the answer is always thermal control" see https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26889/6944