# What was the leeward surface temperature of the Apollo Command Module during reentry?

Tags: reentry, aerodynamics, temperature, command-module

From the [Apollo Experience Report: Thermal Protection System](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19740007423), there is a diagram that shows the surface temperatures of the Command Module at various points (image was obtained from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36611/32284)). It shows about 1500 °F (816 °C).

[image]

From [Apollo Infrared Acquisition and Tracking System](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hjsVvmJEE_gC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) on Google Books, on page 26, there is a graph showing the temperature of the leeward side. Here it shows the temperature around 1250 °F (676 °C).

[image]

However, in the Apollo Command Module recovery photographs, only one half of the CM still has Mylar on the surface. This is the Apollo 13 CM.

[image]

My initial thought was that the spacecraft re-entered at a non zero angle of attack as that was how they controlled lift. But Mylar and Aluminum have melting points of 250 °C and 660 °C, respectively. How is it that the Mylar and the Aluminum handles survived re-entry?

**Question:** What was the leeward surface temperature of the Apollo Command Module during re-entry? And how did the Mylar and Aluminum survive?

Comment: The outer film was Kapton.  Mylar was used to protect the surface during manufacturing, but was removed before flight.

Comment: The Mylar/Kapton distinction is explained in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35971/26446) and is based on the *Apollo Experience Report* cited above.

Comment: Added text "leeward side" to the first image.

Comment: @DrSheldon I suppose the same question could apply. Kapton is stable up to 400 °C. What was the leeward side temperature and how did the Kapton and Aluminum parts survive?

Comment: Note that just because the temperature on the outside reaches 676°C, that doesn't mean the Aluminium gets the same temperature. In fact, it would take some time to reach equilibrium with the outside temp. I wasn't able to find a good source for convective heat transfer of aluminium in this regime, though.

Comment: @Polygnome It says the _surface_ temperature is 1500 or 1250 °F.