# Is there any evidence that NASA was worried about deep lunar dust?

Tags: the-moon, nasa, history, dust, regolith

It was once theorized that the moon might have deep oceans of dust, potentially a problem for any craft landing on its surface.  I've heard that NASA was concerned about this possibility in the early days of the Space Race.

**Is there any evidence that deep lunar dust was an actual concern at NASA?**

<sup><sub>Apparently the depth of the lunar dust has become a topic of discussion for young-Earth creationists, making it incredibly hard to search for useful information about the topic.</sub></sup>

Comment: Keep in mind that NASA had hard-landed Rangers and soft-landed Surveyors before any human missions were sent.  If there were any concerns, they were long gone before Apollo landers were designed. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Surveyor_3-Apollo_12.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble, that seems quite reasonable.  I'll take out the comment about Apollo 11 so it doesn't throw people off.  NASA concerns about a deep dust layer from before the Ranger program would still answer the question.

Comment: The primary goal of the Surveyor missions was to demonstrate the feasibility of soft-landing on the moon; the composition of the surface was definitely a big concern, and NASA took the deep dust possibility seriously, even though it was a minority opinion by the time the Surveyors flew.

Comment: No one remembers the second line, do they? "That's one small step for a man, one giant leap for mankind. **And the surface is fine and powdery. I can pick it up loosely with my toe.**" Of all the things to comment on first, it was the dust!

Comment: *"Ooh, it's all sticky! It's covered in jam!"* –[Eddie Izzard](https://www.google.com/search?q=dress+to+kill&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @OrganicMarble: I don't think the Ranger missions settled the question, though the Surveyors did.

Comment: Not NASA but this book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fall_of_Moondust is hard sci-fi and using just this possibility as the setting of the story.

Comment: I don't know how to square the reasonable assertion made in these comments -- that it was know with confidence from unmanned landers that the dust wasn't deep -- with this quote about the Apollo 11 risk assessment: “There was still a debate about if you stepped on to the Moon, would you step into 10ft of dust?” says former Nasa official Scott Hubbard. https://www.ft.com/content/5adc069a-9d27-11e9-b8ce-8b459ed04726 Perhaps there was a worry that dust depth varied a lot and the unmanned probes happened to land in areas where it was shallow.

Comment: @JessRiedel, there's confidence and then there's confidence.  I can read about test results for an experiment all day, but when my life depends on the results, suddenly all those settled questions don't feel quite so settled anymore.  We risked unmanned landers and gained some data showing there probably wasn't an ocean of dust on the moon.  Then we dropped people on the moon and had to trust that our data was correct and predictive.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes.

The fear that lunar dust was fine, deep, and motile enough that a lander could sink under its surface was mostly backed by [Thomas Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Gold#Relationship_with_NASA), a noted astrophysicist who was a consultant to NASA in the 1950s.

Note especially in the image below of a [Popular Mechanics](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=PuMDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=proponent%20lunar%20deep%20surface%20dust&source=bl&ots=qadnp5muJx&sig=Pt_bUfppcmfpM23tFEk7grlVLXk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMIyq-2lvyhxwIVRpMNCh1T1wCi#v=onepage&q=proponent%20lunar%20deep%20surface%20dust&f=false) article from 1964, the quote from his article in Science magazine on the subject: 
"Without any clear signs [in Ranger images]
of firm rock, the pictures must lead to more concern about sinkage of  impact."

[image: popular mechanics article on ranger mission and moon dust]

He became in the small minority in this thinking over time and isolated in his position, but he stuck to his guns. There were [some](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=IoHnPR92Aw0C&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=lunar%20lander%20will%20sink%20in%20dust&source=bl&ots=P3NPFCL0vr&sig=3A1w_LF3wXbG7qE7jIcDxTlDsNs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBjgKahUKEwjjwOaB-6HHAhWGjA0KHdS4Auc#v=onepage&q&f=false) at the time who felt no more needed to be known about the lunar surface before attention could turn to sending people.

Note that this makes him the first person to recognize that the surface of the Moon has been primarily shaped by impacts. The entire surface of the Moon is covered with dust that is tens of meters deep (mixed with larger particles) entirely produced by meteor impacts pulverizing it and throwing it around over billions of years. (You don't *sink* in it, but it's *there*.) This understanding led to the realization that all solar system bodies experienced high levels of collisions for large parts of its history, and research later established that the [Late Heavy Bombardment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Heavy_Bombardment) occurred, and that impacts were a major mechanism of the solar system's evolution. In turn, this realization probably influenced the development of the theory that the Moon was in fact [created](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_impact_hypothesis) by an impact event between early Earth and an object about the size of Mars.

The first Surveyor mission was thus in large part meant to determine whether the dust on the surface would support a spacecraft. From Wikipedia on the [Surveyor program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveyor_program):

> Several Surveyor spacecraft had robotic shovels designed to test lunar
>   soil mechanics. Before the Soviet Luna 9 mission (landing four months
>   before Surveyor 1) and the Surveyor project, it was unknown how deep
>   the dust on the Moon was. If the dust was too deep, then no astronaut
>   could land. The Surveyor program proved that landings were possible.

Comment: @called2voyage i remembered hearing all about it in a talk given by some geologists from the era who had been in the Apollo program. I wish i could remember where.... They expressed a certain ire that the question was given quite so much weight.

Comment: I found a History of Ranger document on NTRS...fascinating reading, but it never said what the mission objectives were. I was hoping it would say something about evaluating the surface properties.  There was one reference to using radar to characterize the surface but it wasn't very detailed.

Comment: Nice answer. Incidentally it also answered my question. Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 17):

The best physical evidence is the fact the foot pads of the lunar lander were dish shaped pads and not something smaller.  This is not evidence of DEEP dust, but of at least the belief there was SOME dust likely to sink into.

[image: From a Lunar Landing denier site, but hey]

Comment: Come to think of it, for a place with 1/6th gravity, those pads are rather large, aren't they.

Comment: Vertical velocity wasn't guaranteed to be zero...

Comment: is that metal foil made of real gold?

Comment: @forestclown: No, [that's a common misconception](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5246/why-is-gold-used-in-space-technology-to-protection-from-heat-radiation). It's actually aluminized [Kapton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapton) (a brownish-colored plastic) used for thermal insulation.

Comment: From [a press release by Grumman about the LEM located at NASA's Apollo Lunar Surface Journal](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM04_Lunar_Module_ppLV1-17.pdf) -- the footpads were 37 inches in diameter to ensure "minimal penetration of the LM on low load-bearing strength lunar surface".

Answer (score 7):

There is an excellent series called ["Moon Machines"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1203167/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) that is often shown on the Science Channel and is also available on DVD. The episode ["The Lunar Module"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1610832/?ref_=ttep_ep4) discusses the fact that NASA was concerned that lunar dust might be deep enough for the lunar lander to sink into it. In my opinion, this series is an excellent documentary of the Apollo Program well worth the time spent to watch it.

Answer (score 6):

[NASA SP-530 "Apollo Expeditions to the Moon"](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-350/ch-5-3.html), edited by Edgar M. Cortright, which is available on the NASA History Program Office website, states that prior to the landing of Surveyor I on the moon:

> Some scientists had theorized that astronauts could be engulfed in dangerously deep dust layers

It does not detail whether these claims were taken seriously by NASA, but it was at least worthy of mention when compiling this record.

Answer (score 2):

Whether covered in dust, or cheese, obviously they had to consider how to get a craft *off* the surface to fulfill the requirement of landing a man on the moon and ***"returning him safely to the earth."*** The last thing you want is an unsteady footing in the lander such that the return vehicle would not operate as intended.

The unorthodox wheels and 12 inch ground clearance on the lunar rover are probably the strongest unspoken evidence that they had no idea what the consistency of the surface was and needed to cover all bases. They did not even deploy the rover until missions had already touched down and returned and dust was still a concern.

[image]

Comment: Development of the LRV wasn't even *contracted* until well after the Apollo 11 landing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Roving_Vehicle#Apollo_Lunar_Roving_Vehicle Plenty of information about the moon's surface was available. The wheel and ground clearance design were informed by knowledge, not ignorance.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: That is precisely my point. The 2008 documentary Moon Machines discusses this ad nauseam. The vehicle maintains traction through its mesh / chevron design despite sinking into dust. The final manned mission even ends with the revelation that underneath top layer of dust is a different material from anything sampled prior.