# Radiation shield for Mars

Tags: spacecraft, radiation, spacesuits, shielding

Earth's magnetic field on its surface is 25 to 65 microtesla. Besides earth's atmospheric protection, majority of sun's harmful radiation on the earth is shielded by this small magnetic field. Such a small magnetic field can easily be produced by a permanent dipole magnet or a small current around the spacecrafts or space suits. Then why the space craft or space suites are not designed with magnetic fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radiation shielding magnetic or mass, which is more efficient?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/797/radiation-shielding-magnetic-or-mass-which-is-more-efficient) or [Research on mini-magnetospheres](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20596/is-nasa-doing-research-on-mini-magnetospheres-to-protect-crew-from-radiation-i?rq=1)

Comment: Consider the *size* of the Earth's field, not just the strength.